# error: DropdownList server error

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have this dropdownlist:

```
<asp:DropDownList runat="server" ID="CatsList" AutoPostBack="True" AppendDataBoundItems="True" DataSourceID="CatsDataSource" DataTextField="CatName" DataValueField="CatId" ClientIDMode="Static" OnSelectedIndexChanged="CatsList_SelectedIndexChanged" OnDataBound="CatsList_DataBound">
    <asp:ListItem Value="1">* SELECT CATEGORY *</asp:ListItem>
</asp:DropDownList>
```

which is working perfect on my local machine, but when I upload it to the server I got this error:

> ### Server Error in '/' Application.
>
> Compilation Error    Description: An error occurred during the
>   compilation of a resource required to service this request. Please
>   review the following specific error details and modify your source
>   code appropriately.
>
> Compiler Error Message: CS1061: 'ASP.categorybrands_aspx' does not
>   contain a definition for 'CatsList_SelectedIndexChanged' and no
>   extension method 'CatsList_SelectedIndexChanged' accepting a first
>   argument of type 'ASP.categorybrands_aspx' could be found (are you
>   missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
>
> Source Error:

```
Line 24:                 <div class="service span3" style="background-color:#fff;border:none;margin-bottom:0px;padding-bottom:0px;">                                      
Line 25:                     <h4 style="color:#ff6a00;font-family:Corbel;">Category</h4>
Line 26:                     <asp:DropDownList runat="server" ID="CatsList" AutoPostBack="True" AppendDataBoundItems="True" DataSourceID="CatsDataSource" DataTextField="CatName" DataValueField="CatId" ClientIDMode="Static" OnSelectedIndexChanged="CatsList_SelectedIndexChanged" OnDataBound="CatsList_DataBound">
Line 27:                         <asp:ListItem Value="1">* SELECT CATEGORY *</asp:ListItem>
Line 28:                     </asp:DropDownList>
```

I have method for `CatsList_SelectedIndexChanged` in my .cs file, really I don't understand the error!

Comment: did you compile? was the compilation OK?

Comment: You need to publish your application to some local folder and then upload content of your publish folder.

Comment: @ Adrian Iftode yes I compiled on my local machine, no errors

Comment: @PrashantLakhlani , could you please explain the purpose of publishing the application??
I uploaded it couple of days ago and it was working, why not now?!

Comment: @Samira so you won't have source .CS files in the compiled production version.

Comment: @Yuriy Galanter I have .cs files

Comment: @Samira *purpose of publishing is to compile all CS files into a single DLL so "production" version should not have them*

Comment: @Yuriy Galanter thx for you explanation I didn't know that
I will try and see
thx again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, it's a silly error but I figured out the solution which is simple!!

1. I cleaned my solution.
2. Rebuild again
3. Re-upload the app. to the server.

It is working now.